# How to add a comma after every existing outputs in php

Tags: php, spacing

I'm trying to add a comma between outputs if they exist. 
If I use implode, comme is display though output string is empty.

```
$data1 = $_GET['data1']; // red
$data2 = $_GET['data2']; //
$data3 = $_GET['data3']; //
$data4 = $_GET['data4']; // green

$result = implode(', ', array($data1, $data2, $data3, $data4));
echo $result; 
// red, , , green :(
// red, green :)
```

UPDATE 
I have multiple keys, which is not the same as the [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58169568/how-to-add-a-comma-after-every-existing-outputs-in-php)

```
www.mysite.com/shoes?size=43 > size is 43
www.mysite.com/shoes?material=leather > material is leather
www.mysite.com/shoes?size=44&color=green > size is 44, color is green
```

Comment: How is that different than the duplicate since you pass all the values into an array. You can still filter the empty elements out of your array.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to send colors as an array:

`http://my-site.com/?colors[]=red&colors[]=green&colors[]=`

Then you can simply do:

```
$result = implode(', ', array_filter($_GET['colors']));
```

Comment: Values result to different keys